# Is there any way to include MahApps' Metro NumericUpDown button?

Tags: c#, styling, numericupdown

I know this control's gonna be relased on MahApps Metro v0.13. However, I do need it now.

I also know there's a good-working Numeric UpDown button from Xceed's Extended Toolkit. But my problem is I need to style the SpinnerButton's arrows and background to different colors during runtime and, as far as I've seen, that's basically impossible to acomplish with it (I spent the whole day trying to do that).

So I guess MahApps' Metro Numeric UpDown button is way more flexible for styling. I'll therefore be grateful if you can tell me what and how to take that control's sources from MahApps's GitHub repo and include it in a Visual Studio 2013 project.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The "answer" was just to include the "prerelease" version of MahApps Metro package in the Visual Studio Project.

To do so, just select the 'Include prereleased version' option in the 'Nuget Package Manager'.

Keep in mind that the prereleased version are unstable. In fact, most of them are even pre-alpha version, which means they haven't even been tested at all.